# Is "Weren't it" wrong?

Tags: grammar

I was watching Eastenders and as you know the Cockney dialect is slightly different from standard English, one of the actors said

"Our anniversary was one of them, weren't it?"
It sounds slightly off to me, as I'd say "Wasn't it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of "were" or "weren't" where "was" or "wasn't" would normally be used, or vice versa, is dialectal.

In your example, "anniversary" is singular so standard English would use "wasn't it?".

Replacing "was" with "were" isn't accepted in standard English.